# Finding $a$, $b$ in a square root function.

Tags: calculus

Given $y=x\sqrt{a+bx^2}$. the tangent to $y$ at point $x=\sqrt5$ is also passing at point

$(3\sqrt5,\sqrt5).$ the area between $y=x\sqrt{a+bx^2}$ and the $x$-axis is equal to $18$.

Need to find $a,b$.

I have tried to differentiate and eliminate but failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x):=x\sqrt{a+bx^2}\implies f(\sqrt5)=\sqrt5\sqrt{a+5b}=\sqrt{5a+25b}\implies$$

since

$$f'(x)=\sqrt{a+bx^2}+\frac{bx^2}{\sqrt{a+bx^2}}=\frac{a+2bx^2}{\sqrt{a+bx^2}}\implies f'(\sqrt5)=\frac{a+10b}{\sqrt{a+5b}}$$

Thus, the tangent line at the tangency point $\;(\sqrt5\,,\,\sqrt{5a+25b})\;$ is

$$y-\sqrt{5a+25b}=\frac{a+10b}{\sqrt{a+5b}}(x-\sqrt5)$$

and as this line passes through $\;(3\sqrt5\,,\,\sqrt5)\;$ , we have that

$$\sqrt5-\sqrt{5a+25b}=\frac{a+10b}{\sqrt{a+5b}}(2\sqrt5)\iff$$

$$10a+25b-2\sqrt{25a+125b}=\frac{20(a^2+20ab+100b^2)}{a+5b}$$

As you can see, we get a first horrendous, awful equation connecting $\;a,b\;$.

The second condition implies that either the function intersects the $\;x$-axis twice, at $\;x=0\;,\;\;x=\sqrt{-\frac ab}\;$ , or else they're talking of the improper integral from zero to $\;+\infty\;$. Anyway, you can use that

$$\int x\sqrt{a+bx^2}dx=\frac1{2b}\int(2bx\,dx)\sqrt{a+bx^2}=\frac1{2b}\frac23(a+bx^2)^{3/2}+C$$

Not the nicest thing (in fact, pretty ugly), but try to take it from here.

Comment: see my comment to @5xum's answer.

Comment: also isn't it clear that it's not improper integral? because we didn't learn that.

Comment: Then it must be that the function vanishes at $\;x=\sqrt{-\frac ab}\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a curve $y=f(x)$, the slope of the tangent at $x_0$ is given by $f'(x_0)$. This means that you have a tangent with the formula $y=f'(x_0)\cdot x + n$ for some real $n$. Plugging in the value $x=x_0$ and $y=f(x_0)$ can then help you calculate $n$ in terms of $a$ and $b$, giving you one of the equations for $a$ and $b$.

For the second part, it's clear that if $b>0$, you need some limit where $x$ may be, otherwise the limit of $a+bx^2$ is $\infty$.

Comment: i got: $a^{1.5}=-27b$ and $\sqrt{a+5b}=25b+3a$
how can i proceed?

Comment: i can see the solution is $a=9,b=-1$ but how can i get it?

Comment: If you have the two equations $a\sqrt a = -27 b$ and $\sqrt{a+5b} = 25b + 3a$ (I haven't double checked if these are correct, though), just solve the two equations and get $a$ and $b$. Replace $b$ with $\frac{-a\sqrt a}{27}$ in the second equation and solve for $a$.

Comment: tried that but it's too complicated

Comment: That @5xum seems easier to say than to do...anyway, you're right but the resulting equation seems to be increidibly hard and ugly.

Comment: @rebbeca, you should check all the data and be 100% sure it is correct. This is an exercise that seems designed to get into despair student or, perhaps, it is designed to be solved with the help of computer programs.

Comment: yes that's all the data and now i see in the book that that's the right answer.. and no it doesn't involve computer program

Comment: Then my heart bleeds for you, @rebbeca...perhaps there's some hidden (for me, of course) trick that makes things simpler. Note that even the given points are ugly, with square roots of five and stuff...

Comment: @rebbeca  what book is that, btw?

Comment: it's a note book of the teacher. he printed it for us.

Comment: The he is a very very cruel man.

Comment: i agree with you but really thanks for the help:)

Comment: This really looks like a made-up exercise in a haste to prove something...and then things go terribly wrong and the exercise looks like one to get your graduate devil diploma from Hell College.